# Multiple networks simultaneously

Tags: wi-fi, root-access, networking, remote-access

I have a wireless sensor (A) that sends the captured data to an Android device (B) over a wifi network created by A.
The data is received correctly on an app running on B, however the problem is that the wifi created by A lacks internet and I need to maintain internet connection on device B.

[image]

From the information I have been able to find, Speedify could accomplish this task, however I need a free alternative. The objective is that B can have internet while using the data reception application that needs to be connected to A's Wi-Fi, perhaps there is some way to force only the application to connect to A's Wi-Fi ( as a possible alternative to the simultaneous use of networks).

Device B would have the possibility of being rooted if this were necessary.

Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77288629/how-to-route-local-traffic-over-wifi-and-everything-else-using-the-mobile-data-i

Comment: What Android version has the phone?

Comment: @Robert I think it is the Android 13 version. According to the documentation https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/wifi-sta-sta-concurrency?hl=es#restricted, it seems that from Android 12 it could be possible What I'm looking for, however, I don't know anything about programming on Android and I don't have access to the application code either..., but this makes me think that maybe there is some way to achieve it.

Comment: @Robert, any ideas?

Comment: Sorry but it seems that there is no demo app available for this feature. At least searching for terms like `isStaConcurrencyForLocalOnlyConnectionsSupported` does not return any existing app code (only versions of the API code). Therefore it seems like you need someone who can develop such an app to test it out if it works (keep in mind that app development is off-topic here).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that while the api has a funtion to allow this, the apps running have to use this function. It isnt just a matter of the Android version, but also the manufacturer (unless rooted) and the apps themselves.

Comment: So is there a way to get several networks to work simultaneously (with root)?